# How to extract data from excel file into c?

Tags: c++, c, excel

I have an excel file which consist of data , I want to extract the data from excel file into a C program for manipulation.  How can I do that?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char StrFile1[200];
    char StrFile2[200];
    clrscr();

    fp = fopen( "NEW.xls", "r");
    fscanf(fp,"%s %s",&StrFile1, &StrFile2);
    fclose(fp);
    fprintf("First Field is %s\nSecond Field is - %s",StrFile1,StrFile2);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
 FILE *fp;
 char StrFile1[200];
 char StrFile2[200];
 clrscr();

 fp = fopen( "NEW.xls", "r");
 fscanf(fp,"%s %s",&StrFile1, &StrFile2);
 fclose(fp);
 fprintf("First Field is %s\nSecond Field is - %s",StrFile1,StrFile2);
 getch();
 return 0;
} @Plunkett

Comment: Any chance you can get the data exported to [tag:csv]? Otherwise you must read the excel format....

Comment: Please don't post code in comments.  Edit your question and put the code in there, so it is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read data from Excel files directly because Excel's `.xls` files are a binary format.  You will need to use a library that is designed to read the XLS format.  Here are two options that I know of:

- [`libxls`](http://libxls.sourceforge.net/) is free and can be used in C++ or in plain C.  It supports only the old binary XLS file type.
- [`LibXL`](http://www.libxl.com/) is not free (free version can read up to 100 rows, purchasing information is on their web site) and is C++ only, but it also has support for the new XML-based XLSX format.

If you are on a computer that has Excel installed, you can also use the Excel COM object to interact with Excel files.  See [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216686) and [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15837/Accessing-Excel-Spreadsheets-via-C) for some more details.